# Are there any practical differences between constructing a string via strdup() and malloc()?

Tags: c, string, memory-management

Suppose I want to write a function that will produce a string, and while I can set an upper limit on the size of the string I don’t know in advance exactly how much space the string will take up. I can think of two ways to arrange this:

```
char *ParametersAsString_1(int temperature, float pressure)
{
    char buffer1[128];
    snprintf(buffer1, 128, "temperature: %d; pressure: %g",
        temperature, pressure);
    return strdup(buffer1);
}

char *ParametersAsString_2(int temperature, float pressure)
{
    char *buffer2 = malloc(128);
    snprintf(buffer2, 128, "temperature: %d; pressure: %g",
        temperature, pressure);
    return buffer2;
}
```

The only difference I can see is that the second form will potentially waste a bit of memory: it uses 128 bytes for `buffer2` for that variable’s entire existence. The first function uses 128 bytes for `buffer1` plus whatever memory the string “actually” uses, but when `buffer1` is removed from the stack the only memory that will be used is whatever the string actually needs.

It looks like the first function would be better if the strings are long-lived and there will be a bunch of them. Are there any other reasons to prefer one of these forms over the other? (This is an academic question; I’m not actually in a situation where using an extra 90 bytes makes a difference.)

Comment: *"The only difference I can see is that the second form will potentially waste a bit of memory"* - It will actually waste a whole lot more if called often, no? And your title doesn't really match your question, since you always use `strdup`. It's rather dynamic vs static allocation of the temporary string that you're after.

Comment: Your approach is buggy — `snprintf()` may not terminate your string with `\0`. Read a manual page or something...

Comment: @LBg your edit of code makes sense for the question however it's a significant difference... one that should not be edited by someone other than the actual question poster since you cannot be certain he meant what you edited to. That is... how do you know the poster isn't actually using the broken code that you changed?

Comment: @n.m. So does the first one if nobody frees the memory. strdup allocates memory dynamically as well.

Comment: @LBg Aaaaahhhhh, with the edit the whole thing makes much more sense now. But I still have to second *mah*.

Comment: @mah, Yes, I think you are right. I just realized the question makes no sense without this edit. bdesham, please undo the edit if it is indeed incorrect

Comment: My version ended the second function with `return buffer2`, not `return strdup(buffer2)`. Does the former cause a memory leak or something?

Comment: Rolled back invalid 3rd party edit - don't alter questions in ways that distort what the actual question was.

Comment: @bdesham review the edit history on your question to see that your post actually had `return strdup(buffer2);` which introduced an unnecessary copy and leak. If you actually do return buffer2, then your two functions are essentially identical.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Why isn't it safe to use `snprintf()` as long as I know that the resulting string will fit within the buffer?

Comment: @VladLazarenko `snprintf()` always terminates the string, you are thinking about the `strncpy()`. It's the second pargraph in the [manpage](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/3posix/snprintf/)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Not true -- `snprintf` will always null terminate what it puts in the buffer (unless the buffer size is 0).

Comment: A possibly practical difference is that `malloc`, being Standard C, is more portable than `strdup`.

Comment: `ParametersAsString_2` has a memory leak - buffer2 `malloc`ed but never `free`ed - perhaps you meant to just return buffer2 and not `strdup` it.  A copy-and-paste bug?

Comment: Hm. I reckon Microsoft's implementation was not doing proper '\0' termination.

Comment: @kfmfe04 That `strdup` got in there because of a bad edit, which SO seems to have cached or something...

Comment: @bdesham please edit the question accordingly, so that others can help you better..

Comment: @VoidPointer No, because someone rolled back. I just undid the rollback by another rollback.

Comment: @glglgl I had rolled back the edit to **bdesham's own original** version with strdup(), removing the **invalid** 3rd party edit.  If bdesham actually mistyped in the post, it was bdesham, *and not someone else speculating*, who should have changed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for minimum memory usage not knowing the length beforehand, the solution lies in a special usage of `snprintf`. From the C11 standard:

> 7.21.6.5
>
> 2. .. If n is zero, nothing is written, and s may be a null pointer...
>
> 3. The snprintf function returns the number of characters that would have been written
>   had n been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative
>   value if an encoding error occurred...

This means that if you write:

```
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "format string", arguments);
```

you will either get a negative value showing error (unlikely) or a positive value saying what would the ultimate size of the string be, without actually writing that string anywhere.

Therefore:

```
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "temperature: %d; pressure: %g", temperature, pressure);
/* error checking */
char *str = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*str));
/* error checking */
sprintf(str, "temperature: %d; pressure: %g", temperature, pressure);
return str;
```

Note that `strdup` and `asprintf` are not standard. The former is a POSIX extension and the later is a GNU extension.

---

This solution will give you an unbounded string, so it's quite useful (you don't have to cut the string). However, if you do want to cut the string, simply allocate a smaller memory if `size` was too big and use `snprintf` with the proper size to create the (cut) string in the buffer.

---

If you want to be more secure and future proof as well as avoid repeating code, you can use a macro:

```
#define YOUR_LIB_YOUR_FUNC_NAME_SNPRINTF(s, n)               \
             snprintf(s, n, "temperature: %d; pressure: %g", \
             temperature, pressure)

int size = YOUR_LIB_YOUR_FUNC_NAME_SNPRINTF(NULL, 0);
/* error checking */
char *str = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*str));
/* error checking */
YOUR_LIB_YOUR_FUNC_NAME_SNPRINTF(str, size + 1)
return str;

#undef YOUR_LIB_YOUR_FUNC_NAME_SNPRINTF
```

In fact, modifying this function a little bit to work with `vsnprintf`, you get an implementation of `asprintf` that you could use wherever needed.

Comment: When someone edits this code next year and changes one format string but neglects to change the other, you get a buffer overrun. I would use `snprintf` for the second call (buffer overruns merit paranoid programming), and probably factor out the format string too. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: @nemo, right. The only thing I don't like about this method myself is the redoing of `snprintf`. Anyway, the format string better not be factored out by itself, since compilers tend to look out for you making mistakes in the format string if it is literal. But can be do in another way. I'll edit right away.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use asprintf. buffer will be allocated with the needed size... (This pointer should be passed to free() to release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed)

```
char*   ParametersAsString_3(int temp, float pres) {                                                                                                                                        
    char* buffer;                                                                                                                                                                         

    asprintf(&buffer, "temperature: %d; pressure: %g", temp, pres);                                                                                                                           
    return (buffer);                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, neither strdup() nor asprintf() are C; they are platform-specific extensions to C. And the OP did not specify any platform.

Comment: True. For a standard solution, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17091469/912144).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `asprintf()`; I'd never heard of it before. Since it's non-standard, though, I'll go with Shahbaz's answer, which is portable (although it probably uses the same code as `asprintf()` under the hood).

Answer (score 1):

As to the question in title: strdup() uses malloc(). It means that after strdup you should use free().

As to the examples, the second function allocates memory without freeing, the first not, so forget the second. Still, for the first function, you should free the functions result once you don't need it.

EDIT: the question was edited, so the answer must be edited too :)

Before the question was edited, the second function ended with strdup(buffer2). I meant in my answer, that the second function leacks memory allocated for buffer2. Both functions, as they were then, returned address that should be freed afterwards, but the second would cause additional leack.

Comment: The first example also allocates memory without freeing, for the exact reason you include in your answer: strdup() uses malloc(). Unless you are refering to the pre-LBg edit on the question (which included a memory leak in the second example)?

Comment: Before the question was edited, the second function ended with strdup(buffer2). I meant in my answer, that the second function leacks memory allocated for buffer2. Both functions, as they were then, returned address that should be freed afterwards, but the second would cause additional leack.

Answer (score 0):

`strdup` calls `malloc` and `memcpy` internally. So **Function 1** has extra cost of calling `memcpy` function.

So **Function 2** looks better option considering this reason along with reasons specified by @shahbaz.